# Dynamically running Python scripts pulled from SQL query

Tags: python, function

I have a Python script that in the middle of it will have a function where I want to query a DB table and run whatever Python scripts are listed in one of the columns.  The Python scripts themselves reside in the same folder as the main Python script that is being executed.  For specific reasons I need to keep these script names in a DB table though and call/read them from there, hence my issue.

python_script_table in DB looks like:

```
TABLE_ID    PYTHON_SCRIPT
1           script1.py
2           script2.py
3           null
```

Query would be something like:

```
select * from python_script_table where python_script is not null
```

At that point I want to execute whatever is returned under PYTHON_SCRIPT (in this case script1.py and script2.py).

I am unsure the best way to approach this..

Comment: You could also store the path to the script and then call the script from the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: storing the path of the script, instead of the script name is also fine.  Thanks Bernie.  I will check out the subprocess module

Comment: Other alternatives would be to open and read them into a string and then either [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) it or "import" it using the [`__import__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) functions.

Comment: thanks @martineau...so something like this would work?  exec(/path/to/file/script1.py) ?

Comment: No, you would need to `with open('path/to/script.py') as file:`, `script = file.read()`, then `exec(script)`. Both `exec()` and `__import__()` execute the script within the current process, not as a separate process—which may or may not be desirable depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  Makes sense,  I will give it a try

Comment: @martineau  this worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to execute the scripts with something like this:

```
with open('path/to/script.py') as file:
    script = file.read()
    exec(script)
```